# Parallel threads/telnet with Python: can't use len(list) > 1000

Tags: python-3.x, threadpool, python-multithreading

I have a program that will receive a list holding the IP addresses of routers. For each of those, a telnet connection will be triggered over an SSH tunnel.

This is working nice. Except for the fact that if the list is bigger than 1000 addresses (i.e. 1250) only the first 1000 elements will be taken into account. The first 1000 will be ok, but the remaining 250 will not even be considered.

So, first, the pseudo-code:

1. open ssh connection to server and bring up ssh tunnel. return local port
2. open telnet connection to remote router, using local port
3. do something
4. close telnet
5. close ssh

The number of parallel connections is a fixed integer (10, 20, 30, etc). I've tested the code with 40 parallel connections.

This is the code itself.

```
import ipaddress as ip
import threading
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool,Pool
import paramiko
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

class connTelnet(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self,thrdNum, script, loopback):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.num            = thrdNum
        self.script         = script
        self.loopback       = loopback
        self.strConn        = "Con-" + str(self.num) + "| "

def run(self):
    self.s = self.sshStart(self.strConn,self.loopback)
    self.sshStatus = self.s[0]
    self.sshServer = self.s[1]
    self.localPort = self.s[2]

    if self.sshStatus == 1:
        print(self.strConn + ": Quitting....")
        self.sshStop(self.sshServer,self.strConn,self.num)

def sshStart(self,strConn,loopback):
    try:
        sshServer = SSHTunnelForwarder(
            (IP, PORT),
            ssh_username = USER,
            ssh_password = PASSWORD,
            remote_bind_address = (loopback, 23),
        )
        sshServer.start()
        localPort = sshServer.local_bind_port
        sshStatus = 1
        print(strConn + "SSH Tunnel Up: " + loopback + ":" + str(localPort))
    except:
        print(strConn + "Error SSH Tunnel")
        sshStatus = -1
        sshServer = -1
        localPort = -1

    return(sshStatus,sshServer,localPort)           

def sshStop(self,sshServer,strConn,num):
        sshServer.stop()
            print(strConn + "SSH" + str(num) + " stopped ...")

def run_mi_thread(i, script, loopback):
    connTelnet(i, script, loopback).run()

    #### Main ####
if __name__ == '__main__':

    progNumThreads = 40
    n = 1010
    a = '99.0.0.0'
    ipaddress = ip.IPv4Address(a)
    routers = [(ipaddress+x).exploded for x in range(1,n)]

    threads_list    = Pool(progNumThreads)
    for i, router in enumerate(routers):

        # We generate the config file
        script     = "blablabla\n"
        threads_list.apply_async(run_mi_thread, args=(i, script, router))

    threads_list.close()
    threads_list.join()
```

So, as said before, if `len(threads_list) <= 1000`, all the routers will be served. If `len(threads_list) > 1000`, only the first 1000 routers will be served.

More over: **it's very curious that the number is 1000. And it's always the same.** Does not change with several runs of the program.

Would it related some how to amount of parallel sockets? amount of SSH tunnels?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming your OS is Linux, it's probably related to the limit of opened files per process. You can check with `ulimit -n` and you'll probably get `1024` as the response. Con be configured in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.